# javascript being blocked in HTTPS secure server

Tags: javascript, https

Our client is using an HTTPS sharepoint server. This is blocking all the javascript files in the html page. The html sliders and the image gallery is not showing on the page. All the javascipt files are blocked as blocked content. Please tell me a workaround, how i can use the javascript files without being blocked and make the components work properly.

Comment: Please suggest me a workaround. I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that you are referencing the external resources insecurely.  Make sure you are using `https://` on all of your external javascript and image references.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If i refer to all the javascript resources with relative path eg. <script src="js/lightslider.js"> will it work or it will still be blocked resource.

Comment: Yes, the relative paths will all follow the protocol in the address bar either http or https.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. When i run my html page in my local machine on internet explorer, I am getting a message that "Internet explorer restricted this web page from running scripts or activex controls". When i put the file in client HTTPS server, will the scripts be blocked. How can i check whether it will work properly or not.

Comment: Try setting up a LAMP server to test is locally.  If you are running Javascript from  `file:///somewhere_local`, you will get Javascript warnings like the one you mentioned.

Comment: hi, Please can you elaborate on this setting up of LAMP server to test the website. I donot know how to do this. Also if i include the javascript as <script src="https://www.abcd.com/js/jquery.royalslider.min.js"> will it then be an unblocked resource.

Comment: Search google for setting up lamp, that will be a whole new discussion here.  As to your second question, it depends on how you are running the html.  Try it and see.  Make sure you add `https://` to you url for the js file.